# Sending Emails with Amazon SES and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ses

I have s SpringBoot app. with this dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-ses</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

this config file:

```
@Configuration
public class MailConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService() {

        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("ses-smtp-user.234221-1724219"))
                .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_2)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MailSender mailSender(
            AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Service
public class NotificationService {
    
    private final MailSender mailSender;
    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public NotificationService(MailSender mailSender, JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    public void sendMailMessage(
            final SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {

        this.mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);
    }

}
```

but when I start the app. I have this error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.dis.backend.service.NotificationService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Sure, your configuration class is being picked up by Spring? Might be a package issue. Show the packages of each class and of your main class.

Comment: `SimpleEmailServiceMailSender` does not implement `JavaMailSender` interface. I think you would want to inject `MailSender` instead of `JavaMailSender` in `NotificationService`.

Comment: Based on the error message, remove the `JavaMailSender` constructor argument in the `NotificationService` constructor as you are not using that in the NotificationService. In case you wanted to also use the `JavaMailSender` in the `NotificationService`, you need to create a bean of type `JavaMailSender` which can be injected in the `NoficationService`

Comment: Yes, @GSSwain, I agree with you, that is the problem. Please, consider post the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, remove the `JavaMailSender` constructor argument in the `NotificationService` constructor (assuming you are not using that in the `NotificationService`).

In case you wanted to use the `JavaMailSender` in the `NotificationService`, you would need to create a `Bean` of type `JavaMailSender` which can be injected in the `NotificationService`. For AWS-SES, you can do so by defining the following bean in your configuration.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService){
    return new SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
}
```

Comment: I am happy to see that you posted the answer and that it was the accepted one.

Comment: @jccampanero appreciate that, generally people would go ahead and post as their own answer!

Comment: Thank you very much @GSSwain. It would have been very unfair, you provided a very detailed explanation of the problem. You deserve all the credit.

Comment: Late question but, what would be the equivalent of this with new aws-sdk-java-v2? I saw that `software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.SesClient` is mentioned here but couldn't figure out how to use it with JavaMailSender. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/master/docs/LaunchChangelog.md